# Dictionary key in list 1 contains list 2 key, but they are not exactly the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    dict1 =  {'VE-VOLDA-385': 'L_741405088655871', 
              'VE-EIRA-313': 'L_741405088655872', 
              'VE-SUNNFJORD-077': 'L_741405088655873',
              'PIER-BUAVAG-117': 'L_74140508865602'}
    
    dict2 = {'EIRA': '9261621',
             'VOLDA': '9254898',
             'SUNNFJORD': '7710501'}
```

I have two dictionaries I have got from two APIs. The second dictionary value contains the data I would like to match to the first dictionary. How can I match these two on the key?
Also as there is some items in dict1 that should not be matched to dict2 I can't just sort them alphabetically.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: reset the key in dict1 based on parsing the existing key maybe with regex or split

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys have the form given in your question, it is easy enough to extract the part of the key that you are interested in:

```
dict1 =  {'VE-VOLDA-385': 'L_741405088655871',
          'VE-EIRA-313': 'L_741405088655872',
          'VE-SUNNFJORD-077': 'L_741405088655873',
          'PIER-BUAVAG-117': 'L_74140508865602'}
    
dict2 = {'EIRA': '9261621',
         'VOLDA': '9254898',
         'SUNNFJORD': '7710501'}

keys1 = {k.split('-')[1] for k in dict1}
keys2 = set(dict2)
common_keys = keys1 & keys2
print(common_keys) #{'EIRA', 'SUNNFJORD', 'VOLDA'}
```